# When launching the application the string appears as null

Tags: json, parsing, dart, flutter

As the title has said, whenever I run the flutter application in my phone (debug mode atm, I don't know if it will work correctly in release mode). The dndguide.toString() appears as null. However, upon a hot reload the string appears normally. Is there a way to avoid this and make it work correctly upon launching? I suspect I put the loadjson() call in the wrong location, but I've tried shaping the code so that the function is called in different areas and no success.

Here is the code for the application:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

var dndguide;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<String> _loadAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/HDARG.json');
  }

  Future loadjson() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    dndguide = jsonResponse;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadjson();
    var scrollcontroller;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 24,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollcontroller,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Text(dndguide.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json` response is called asynchronously, which why the first time it gives `null` and after hot reloading it appears successfully. You should put some placeholder value into your `dndguide` variable or call the `json` in the `initState()` function of your `_MyHomePageState` instead of calling it during `build` process:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   loadjson();
 }
```

Comment: I've added the @override to the _MyHomePageState class as you've suggested but the problem still persists. It only shows after a hot refresh. Could it be an issue with the async itself?

Comment: A `FutureBuilder` will be suitable for your case.which will begin building your widget only after the data is recieved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634418/how-to-properly-wait-until-future-is-complete-in-dart/54634695#54634695

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. With FutureBuilder I removed almost everything that was causing me problems.