# (Flutter) How to launch static html page instead of URL if there is no internet connection?

Tags: flutter, dart, uiwebview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have flutter_webview_plugin installed. I am trying to launch a custom static html page instead of my URL(my website 'wwww.duevents.in') if there is no internet connection, since the "Web Page not available" page doesn't look very professional.

I am using this to check the internet on the device and it is working fine ('connectionStatus ==true' when the internet is connected and vice versa):

```
Future check() async {
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    connectionStatus = true;
    print("connected $connectionStatus");
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  connectionStatus = false;
  print("not connected $connectionStatus");
}
```

}

This is the code where I have alternate URLs to load if there is no internet connection:

```
WebviewScaffold(      
  url: connectionStatus == true ?"http://www.duevents.in" : Uri.dataFromString('<html><body>hello world</body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString())
```

**Somehow it always shows me the HTML Page with this code no matter if the device has an internet connection or not**. Please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: Did you try using a `FutureBuilder` ?

Comment: @Mazin No. where do I need it here?

Comment: this solution will help you implement `FutureBuilder` so you can check for connection status only after it is fetched https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634418/how-to-properly-wait-until-future-is-complete-in-dart/54634695#54634695

Comment: what should I assign to 'future:'?
P.S. I apologize for asking a lot of questions, I am new to this stuff, so i Know very little.

Comment: Your `check()` method. So it'll be `future: check(),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided by @Mazin Ibrahim in the comments above worked for me.

So I am posting the solution here:

```
    FutureBuilder(
        future: check(), // a previously-obtained Future or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (connectionStatus == true) {
           //if Internet is connected
            return SafeArea(
                child: WebviewScaffold(
              url: "http://www.duevents.in"))}
               else{ 
                //If internet is not connected
                  return SafeArea(
                 child: WebviewScaffold(
                  url: Uri.dataFromString('<html><body>hello world</body></html>',
                    mimeType: 'text/html').toString()) }})
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the `check()` method to return the URL directly.

```dart
Future<String> getURL() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return "http://www.duevents.in";
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Uri.dataFromString('<html><body>hello world</body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString();
    }
}
```

So then in the `FutureBuilder` you could use the URL returned straight away.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
        future: getURL(), // a previously-obtained Future or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, String url) {
            return SafeArea(
                child: WebviewScaffold(
                url: url))}
           })
```