# Flutter - How to get value from shared preferences in a non-async method

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to get some values saved in the `SharedPreferences` from a getter method of a class. But `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` returns a `Future`. Is there a way to obtain the `SharedPreferences` object in a non-`async` getter methods, for example:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyClass {
  get someValue {
    return _sharedPreferencesObject.getString("someKey");
  } 
}
```

Is there something in Dart that is similar to `.Result` property in C#, for example `getSomethingAsync().Result` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634418/how-to-properly-wait-until-future-is-complete-in-dart/54634695#54634695

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: Access Stored Sharedpreference value from Other Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215064/flutter-access-stored-sharedpreference-value-from-other-pages)

Comment: Hi @CopsOnRoad, I knew those solutions but my question is more about whether there's a way to wait for future object to return in a non-async method. I edited my question to make it a bit clearer (I hope).

Comment: @Dean, I am not aware of your use case, but the good thing would be to get the `SharedPreferences` on app startup and after this use it when you need. You can  also instantiate it in Splash screen of your app.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad, that's what I am doing at the moment. The answer to my question would be 'it's not possible'.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `FutureBuilder()`

```dart
late final SharedPreferences _prefs;
late final _prefsFuture = SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((v) => _prefs = v);
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _prefsFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return YourFinalWidget(); // `_prefs` is ready for use.
        }

        // `_prefs` is not ready yet, show loading bar till then.
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: you're a life saver, I saw so many answers for that question, none of them worked for me, but you saved my day, salute sir!

Answer (score 20):

You can do it in `initState()` and after this call `setState()` to update your `build()` method. Other way is to use `FutureBuilder()`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    setState(() => sharedPrefs = prefs);
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because async won't work in that initState

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla `setState` is called in an anonymous function (not in `initState` function), so the above code *works*. I don't mind downvotes as long as they make some sense.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I am wrong, Just trying to understand.  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();  this is an async call so as per docs the initState can't handle the async calls in it. There is no problem in calling the setState.  https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Where did I use `await` inside `initState`?

Comment: There is no await call in your code that's why I feel it's not correct. SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla You don't need `await` to await on a future. `then` does the job too, hence my code exists in the `initState`.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use GetStorage

**https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage**

you will be able to get values without awaiting for them

**main.dart**

```
await GetStorage.init();
runApp(MyApp());
```

**storage.dart**

```
  static bool isFirstOpen() {
    final box = GetStorage();
    return box.read("isFirstOpen") ?? true;
  }

  static  setFirstOpen(bool isopen) {
    final box = GetStorage();
    box.write("isFirstOpen", isopen);
  }
```

Comment: not a bad alternative to shared preferences

Comment: This works, but since you need to use `await GetStorage.init()` in `main() async`, you may as well be calling `prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` instead, in the same exact place. Then you don't need to switch to another library (also GetStorage only stores strings, SharedPreferences has typed data). See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only async call in SharedPreferences is to get the initial instance. This can be reused across your application. `main` can be `async`. So you can just `await` the `SharedPreferences` instance in `main`:

```dart
late SharedPreferences prefs;

main() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(App());
}
```

Now you can use `prefs` anywhere without resorting to `async` code. `SharedPreferences` will serve as a nonblocking write-through cache, with write operations running asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

- Create a separate shared preferences service
- Take in the `SharedPreferences` value in the constructor
- You can then do get call without async, await

Example

```dart
class SharedPreferencesService {
  final SharedPreferences _prefs;

  const SharedPreferencesService(this._prefs);

  Future<void> setString(String key, String value) async {
    await _prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  String? getString(String key) {
    if (containsKey(key)) {
      return _prefs.getString(key);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  bool containsKey(String key) {
    return _prefs.containsKey(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call a function on `initState()` and save SharedPreferences in a variable, so you can use in a non-async method, like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

Future<void> loadPrefs() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  loadPrefs();
}
```

Comment: That won't work -- loadPrefs() will return immediately and get scheduled for async execution. Anything accessing `prefs` may or may not get the actual instance, depending on timing (this is a race condition). Also you would need `SharedPreferences?` as the type of `prefs`, or this won't compile.