# Can i put List into SharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

Can I put `ArrayList` or `List` object to `SharedPreferences` in Flutter? Cause I just realized that flutter haven't gson in their dart

So..i want to save like favorite books by tapping star icon, and when I tap that, that books will be saved in sharedPreferences.

and I can see the list of my favorite books.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Save:**

```dart
prefs.setStringList('key', yourList);
```

**Retrieve:**

```dart
var yourList = prefs.getStringList('key');
```

Comment: so,,can i put more int variable into one ID?

Comment: I updated the code, let me know if that suits your need.

Comment: means i can only put one favorite books sir?

Comment: In flutter we don't have `ArrayList`, we have just `List`. You should be able to save it as long as it is a list of `String`.

Comment: I'm getting this error

The method 'setStringList' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: setStringList("list", Instance(length:9) of '_GrowableList')

Comment: @kirubhasankar You need to initialise your `SharedPreferences` object, which I didn't do in this code sample. Here is a solution on [how to do initialise a `SharedPreferences` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402192/6618622)

Comment: It's worked. you saved my time, Thank you@CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 1):

By ArrayList if you mean List data-structure of Flutter, then you can save only List in SharedPreference using this method:

```
Future <bool> setStringList(String key, List<String> value)
```

And you can fetch the list with:

```
List<String> getStringList(String key)
```

For more information about shared_preferences go through [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/shared-preferences-how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-554d08671ae9) article.

**Some free advice:**
SharedPreferences are meant to save data that is in key-value pair and are related to user's setting. It should not save any complex data like List of custom objects.

If you are having a need to store data that is more complex than that, consider using SQLite.

Comment: Why shared preferences should not save any complex data like List of custom objects??

Comment: It was designed to save user preferences so it basically is designed to save key value pairs like key: "Theme" value: "Dark" and etc.. etc.. for more complex structure you should be using databases like sqflite, moor or no SQL databases like Hive. you can always serialize data and store it in SharedPreferences but just because you are allowed to do that doesn't mean you should. I would say go for hive if you want to save complex data.