# Flutter - How to Store a List of String

Tags: flutter

I have to save data for an inventory. I organized them as a string list, how can I proceed? Reading and writing to a file does not seem to be suitable because writing will overwrite (so can’t easily update) and reading would cause the structure to be lost. Please help me!

Comment: You could use a database, for example via the [sqflite-Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)

Comment: [shared_preferences - plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) will help you store string list, check there example code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636980/can-i-put-list-into-sharedpreferences-in-flutter/55637008#55637008

Answer (score 2):

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
```

2. Install it, You can install packages from the command line:

```
$ flutter packages get
```

3. Import it, Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Here is how you store and get the list of string back:

```dart
String listKey = "listKey";

void storeStringList(List<String> list) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setStringList(listKey, list);
}

Future<List<String>> getStringList() async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await prefs.getStringList(listKey);
}
```

This is how you can get that list

```dart
getStringList((List<String> strList){
  //strList is the string that you stored.
});
```

Comment: hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use Future<List<String>> in code. There are some child of widget linked to that value and I can't use the Future.... How can I convert Future String into String?

Comment: do it this way. `futureStr.then((str){//str is astring})`. You can search about async execution in dart to know more about Future API

Comment: Please mark the answere correct, if it is what you where looking for

Comment: Sill having problems. Can you post a sample code of this Future to String conversion?