# Flutter: Save and Fetching multiple value in SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm working with [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-) to make feature offline bookmark News . i can saved and fetching single value with this code :

#### Saved Value

```
void _testingSavePref(String judulBerita) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setString("tokenbookmark", judulBerita);
  }
```

#### Fetching Value

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _testingLoadPref();
    });
  }
_testingLoadPref() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      tokenBookmark = pref.getString("tokenbookmark");
    });
  }
```

Everything is oke , but it's possible to saved and fetching multiple value with [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-) ?

Example,  i have 2 or more data, i want all data saved and not overwrite.

[image]
Thank's

Comment: You might want to check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316208/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences-flutter

Comment: As well as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636980/can-i-put-list-into-sharedpreferences-in-flutter and this article https://medium.com/better-programming/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code:

For Saving Values

```
void _testingSavePref(List<String> judulBerita) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await pref.setStringList("tokenbookmark", judulBerita); //judulBerita is a list of string now
  }
```

For Fetching Values

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _testingLoadPref();
    });
  }

_testingLoadPref() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
       final List<String>? tokenBookmark = pref.getStringList("tokenbookmark");
    });
  }
```

Now, You can get the data from `tokenBookmark` list by below code

```
for(String s in tokenBookmark){
  print(s);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use SharedPreferences to save that kind of data.

Use a local sql or nosql database (sqflite / sembast).

Also don't call setState inside the initState method is wrong and unnecessary.

Comment: Well can you elaborate? In my experience sqflite tends to have very obscure bugs on usage in flutter, the other packages are not lightweight and could be dropped any moment. Also I don't see any issue here to use Sharedpreferences as the data does not need to be secured imho and a JSON file to encode-decode should do just fine.