# how to accommodate an input into a list array in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

how to accommodate an input into a list array with shared preferences?

I made a code like below

```
handlesave() async {
      SharedPreferences ref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      List<String> _arr = [];

      var idU = user.user.id;
      final dataJ = JobStorageModel(
        iduser: idU.toString(),
        id: widget.job.id,
        job_title: widget.job.job_title,
        location: widget.job.location,
      );
      String json = jsonEncode(dataJ);
      print('save -> $json');
      ref.setString('bookmark', json);
}
```

so that it becomes a list array like the following

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "iduser": "1",
  "job_title": "Designer",
  "location": "monggola"
},
{
  "ID": 2,
  "iduser": "1",
  "job_title": "UX",
  "location": "singapore"
}
```

Comment: This might be worth checking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316208/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences-in-flutter

Comment: can you give an example in my code ?

Comment: Did you check the answer that I linked? There is a solution for your problem.

Comment: I've seen it but because I'm still learning, I don't seem to understand

Comment: if you can help me then i will be grateful

Comment: Sorry, I could only repeat what is written there. Seems to be a good answer with upvotes, I suggest that you give it a try.