# Flutter How Save to List with Shared Preference

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

How can I save values to a list with SharedPreferences?

It's a simple list with a date and one value, for example, a list of my weight and sorting the list by date.

Comment: you can check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316208/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot of articles here you are

For Saving data, must be converted to JSON

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   Map<String, dynamic> user = 
    {'weight':[60,70],'height':[70,90]};

bool result = await prefs.setString('user', jsonEncode(user));
```

For Gettin data, must Deconverted from JSON

```
String userPref = prefs.getString('user');
     
Map<String,dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(userPref) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

or

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setStringList('items', <String>['Earth', 'Moon', 'Sun']);
```

Comment: And how i can add dynamic ?

Comment: Can you show example how use the UserMap to show in a listview?