# How store list of String with sharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How can I store the list with sharedPreferences and use it in the ListView?
[this is my shared preferences code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKjLK.png)[and this is my list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRGjV.png)

this is my code:

```
    late SharedPreferences _prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      setState(() => _prefs = prefs);
    });
  }

  _saveList(List<String> list) {
    _prefs.setStringList('key', list);
    print('$_prefs');
  }

  List _fetchList() {
    print('$_prefs');
    return _prefs.getStringList('key') ?? [];
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _saveList(list);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Errori',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Report Errori'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: _fetchList().length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                              child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(_fetchList()[index]),
                            ),
                          ))))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I don't think what I did is correct. I keep having the problem that when I restart the app, the items disappear

Answer (score 0):

To store list of string you can use the following:

```
List<String> stringsList=  ['Alex', 'Mob', 'Flutter'];

final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// store your string list in shared prefs                
prefs.setStringList("stringList", stringsList);
```

To retrieve list of string you can use the following:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

List<String> myStringList = (prefs.getStringList('stringList') ?? List<String>());
```

Comment: i have methods to save and to return the list in sharedpreferences but i don't understand how to recall them in the listview

Comment: Use listview.builder. You will see a parameter called itemCount. Just write there "myStringList.length". This will calculate the length of your list and show items appropriately. For more info on how to code a list please check the link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listview-class-in-flutter/#:~:text=In%20Flutter%2C%20ListView%20is%20a,ListView.

Comment: yeah, I did this but when i restart app disappear all item in listview

Comment: Where do you get your list data from? Is the data static?

Comment: no, I noticed yesterday that with static data it works without problems while I need a dynamic list so it doesn't work

Comment: Now work on restart but not when i close app and re open it

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316208/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences-in-flutter) to save a list of objects to sharedpreferences and you can recall them in the commented place below:

```
itemBuilder(_,_){ 
//Recall the listview method 
return yourWidget;}
```

Comment: i have methods to save and to return the list in sharedpreferences but i don't understand how to recall them in the listview

Comment: I edited my answer have a look please!

Comment: if you did not understand yet, then send or write your code as a text not as an image to copy easily and solve the problem entirely.

Comment: I added the code to the question