# Saving a class within a class - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have class "DilemmData" which I need to save:

```
class DilemmData {
     double percent = 0;
     final String title;
     final String date;
     List<DilemmItemData> plus = [];
     List<DilemmItemData> minus = [];

     DilemmData(
       plus,
       minus, {
       this.percent = 0,
       this.title = '',
       this.date = '',
     });

     static Map<String, dynamic> toJson(DilemmData dilemm) {
       return {
         'percent': dilemm.percent,
         'title': dilemm.title,
         'date': dilemm.date,
         'plus': dilemm.plus.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
         'minus': dilemm.minus.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
       };
     }

     factory DilemmData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       return DilemmData(
         json['plus'],
         json['minus'],
         percent: json['percent'],
         title: json['title'],
         date: json['date'],
       );
     }

     static String encode(List<DilemmData> pressure) => json.encode(
           pressure
              .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((dil) => DilemmData.toJson(dil))
              .toList(),
     );

     static List<DilemmData> decode(String dilemm) =>
         ((json.decode(dilemm) ?? []) as List<dynamic>)
              .map<DilemmData>((dil) => DilemmData.fromJson(dil))
              .toList();
      }

    class DilemmItemData {
        final int importance;
        final String argument;

        DilemmItemData({this.importance = 0, this.argument = ''});

        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
          return {
             'importance': importance,
             'argument': argument,
          };
        }

       factory DilemmItemData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return DilemmItemData(
              importance: json['importance'], argument: json['argument']);
       }
   }
```

There is save function:

```
        DilemmData dilemm = DilemmData(
               percent: 0,
               title: controller.text,
               date: clockString);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

          String data = jsonEncode(dilemm);
          sharedPreferences.setString('dilemms', data);
```

But when i try to save i get this error: **JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DilemmData')**. Does anyone know how to save?

StackOverflow says I have a lot of code, but I don't know what else to write, I'll write random letters for this: shdjfhjjsdfjhwehfwouiehuwefuwefuwheugweghuweghuiweghuwueghuweweugihwueighuwhguwhgu

Here is the function to get the data:

```
  Future loadDillems() async {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
          SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      if (sharedPreferences.containsKey('dilemms')) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
            jsonDecode(sharedPreferences.getString('dilemms')!);
            MyApp.dilemmList = DilemmData.fromJson(data) as List<DilemmData>;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting the "top" class using its `toJson()` method, make sure that the subsequent classes' `toJson()` methods is also called. As such:

```
'plus': dilemm.plus.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
```

And you of course have to implement `toJson()` and `fromJson()` in `DilemmItemData` as well.

### Edit:

Okey, so a couple of alternatives. First of all, you had to create the new `toJson()` (and soon also `fromJson()`) methods. That is good.

As @Ivo wrote, if you pass the object to jsonEncode as you do now, then the methods cannot be static. But you could also pass `DilemmData.toJson(dilemm)` as:

```
String data = jsonEncode(DilemmData.toJson(dilemm));
```

But I'd recommend as @Ivo wrote to make it non-static, as you did with the new toJson method, and of course keep the toJson in DilemmItemData, and I suggest that you write the fromJson as well...

### Second edit:

Your fromJson have to be a bit sharper. Something like this:

```
DilemmData(
  (json['plus'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => DilemmItemData.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
```

### Edit 3:

You are saving one DilemmData, so you have to read it as one (1) DilemmData. Remove the `as List<DilemmData>;` It is not all of a sudden a List when it is one object that you save (`String data = jsonEncode(dilemm);`)

So do as follows:

```
final oneDilemmData = DilemmData.fromJson(data);
```

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: Then you'd have to update your code with the new toJson and fromJson, and show us what `dilemm` is declared as in `String data = jsonEncode(dilemm);`

Comment: I have fromJson in two classes

Comment: Sorry, missed it!

Comment: but now i got a new error when i want to get the data: https://imgur.com/a/UmJvwl3

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: And how to make it so that it can be saved and retrieved as a list?

Comment: First things first. Have you successfully stored and read the data as one object?

Comment: @ RobertSandberg, yes

Comment: Okey. Then I'd like you to accept this answer (and give a vote up) to close this question. And then create a new question. That way things are kept apart and will not be an endless neverending question and answer stream :) This question was "saving a class within a class". Not "saving a list of classes with classes within".

Comment: Ps. Maybe you can just search SO without creating a new question. Perhaps look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316208/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences-in-flutter

Comment: I did everything as in the selected example and I get this exception: _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in the cast)

Comment: As I said, create a new specific question for that specific error. Only add relevant code to the new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your `toJson()` non static like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
        'percent': percent,
        'title': title,
        'date': date,
        'plus': plus,
        'minus': minus,
    };
}
```

your encode could be like this then:

```
static String encode(List<DilemmData> pressure) => json.encode(
    pressure
        .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((dil) => dil.toJson())
        .toList(),
);
```