# Flutter - Shared Preferences : How can I save a List<object>

Tags: flutter, dart

i want save list of object in local memory by `shared_preferences` my Model :

```
class Vehicle {
  final String vehicleId;
  final String vehicleType;

  Vehicle({
    this.vehicleId,
    this.vehicleType,
  });
}
```

after when i search about this i found half-solution :) to convert to `List<String>` and   add this to my class :

```
  factory Vehicle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> vehicleJson){
    return new Vehicle(
      vehicleId: vehicleJson['vehicleId'],
      vehicleType: vehicleJson['vehicleType'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      'vehicleId': this.vehicleId,
      'vehicleType' : this.vehicleType,
    };
  }
```

but i can't found how can i save and get it :(

sorry my English not good

Comment: Does [How to save List<Object> to SharedPreferences in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61316208/10157127) answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot save a list of object with shared preferences but you can encode each object into a string and save it using **setStringList()** function

Example:

```
List<String> vehiculesEncoded = [];

vehicles.forEach((vehicule) {
  vehiculesEncoded.add(vehicule.toJson());
});

sharedPreferences.setStringList("myAmazingListOfVehicules", vehiculesEncoded);
```

Comment: thanks for reply .. i get error >( The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. ) in this line (vehiculesEncoded.add(vehicule.toJson());)

Comment: This could be fixed by changing **vehiculesEncoded.add(vehicule.toJson());** into **vehiculesEncoded.add(jsonEncode(vehicule.toJson()));**

Wrapping **toJson** with **jsonEncode()** will solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

this type of array you have & you want to store it in session

```
List<Vehicle> arrayVehicle = [ your data ];
```

for that  you have to convert array into json string by doing this

```
String strTemp =  json.encode(arrayVehicle);// store this string into session
```

whenever you want to retrive it just decode that string

```
List<Vehicle> arrayVehicle = json.decode(yourSessionValue)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: i get runtime error : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Vehicle>'

Comment: Can you share some code how you store your vehicle values in your model class