# How can I cast or change the data type of a list to use a shared preferences method? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to do a search history using sharedpreferences.

I have a list and I store in that list what I select from the search bar and I can show it in one of the methods to show the search history. That works fine for me, all correct.

But I have to change that list's data type to use the SetStringList method of sharedpreferences because they are different data types and show with a print the data with GetStringList

With historialMenuPrincipal I can show some variable or search information example:: print busqueda.name or historialMenuPrincipal[0].name

How can I change the data type of the list to be able to use it with the shared preferences and show it in the console or show it in a text widget??

Help would be greatly appreciated

Here I leave the code

```
Class ABC{
    IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                 onPressed: () async {
                   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                 
                   final busqueda = await showSearch(
                       context: context,
                       delegate: SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal(
                           "Buscar...", this.historialMenuPrincipal)
                   );
                   if (busqueda != null ) {
                     historialMenuPrincipal.removeWhere((item) =>
                     item.edad== busqueda.edad);
                     this.historialMenuPrincipal.insert(0, busqueda);
                     prefs.setStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences",this.historialMenuPrincipal.insert); //the error apperas hear for the data type of the list

print(prefs.prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences")[0].name);
}})}
```

Comment: Instead of saving `historialMenuPrincipal` as a list of strings, you can save it as a string by calling the `toString` method & create a method to fetch string from `SharedPreferences` & convert it to a list similar to `historicalMenuPrincipal`.

Answer (score 0):

To get names(List) from `historialMenuPrincipal` it can be done with `.map`

```
final names = historialMenuPrincipal.map((e)=>e.name)).toList();
```

Now you can use this `names` to save with

```
prefs.setStringList('HistorialBusquedaPreferences',names);
```

Comment: I want to access all the elements of the list historialMenuPrincipal, not only name

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/61316208/10157127, but I may suggest using other local db , can be hive/isar/sqflite