# How to fix 'NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null'

Tags: flutter

How i can fix this problem
i use function to get data from api, but i see error 'NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null'

My code:

```
Future getData() async{
http.Response response = await http.get('https://myappres.000webhostapp.com/pubg/api.php?action=getskin');
debugPrint(response.body);

_data = json.decode(response.body);
_list = _data['categorys'];

return _list;                                                               
}
```

and

```
 Center(
          child: _list.length != null? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _list.length,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.9),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position){
                final index = position;
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${_list[index]['name']}'),
                    subtitle: Image.network('${_list[index]['image']}',width: 200,)
                );
              }
          ):Container()
        )
```

this is result Error:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634418/how-to-properly-wait-until-future-is-complete-in-dart/54634695#54634695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FutureBuilder to wait for the Future:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
           return Center(child: snapshot.length)
        } else return Container();
      },

//you can use too:
getData().then((listData){
      Center(child: listData)...
});
```

Comment: where i use this please?

Comment: where i use this please? @Norberto Martín Afonso

Comment: try in Widget build(BuildContext context) {